# React Admin forms field width is small and does not fill the form area. Am I doing something wrong?

Tags: react-admin

I think I've missed a step somewhere and I can't tell how to affect the form field widths to enable them to fill the area horizontally.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {
  Edit,
  SimpleForm,
  TextInput,
  ReferenceInput,
  SelectInput,
  ArrayInput,
  SimpleFormIterator,
} from 'react-admin';
import {RichTextInput} from 'ra-input-rich-text';

export const ProductNotesEdit = () => (
  <Edit>
    <SimpleForm>
      <ReferenceInput source="productId" reference="products" label="Product">
        <SelectInput optionText="name" />
      </ReferenceInput>
      <TextInput source="productId" />

      <ReferenceInput source="promptId" reference="ml_prompts" label="Prompt">
        <SelectInput optionText="slug" />
      </ReferenceInput>
      <TextInput source="promptId" />

      <ArrayInput source="contextUrls">
        <SimpleFormIterator>
          <TextInput source="url" />
        </SimpleFormIterator>
      </ArrayInput>

      <ArrayInput source="contextTexts">
        <SimpleFormIterator>
          <TextInput source="text" />
        </SimpleFormIterator>
      </ArrayInput>

      <TextInput source="notes" multiline={true} />
    </SimpleForm>
  </Edit>
);
```

How can I increase the width of the fields?

[Example form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ptXQH.png)
[Source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LbbQ9.png)

Answer (score 2):

So it seems that I'm missing the `fullwidth` argument in my fields.

```
      <TextInput source="notes" multiline fullWidth />
```

Comment: For reference: https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Inputs.html